# Swift: Is there a cleaner way to pass an extra UIBarButtonItem action: Selector parameter other than using button.tag?

Tags: ios, swift, selector, uibarbuttonitem

I'm currently working on a snapchat-like menu where clicking the left and right UIBarButtonItem makes the screen go in their respective directions.

TL;DR - I'm wondering if there's a (clean) built-in way of passing through a tag as an Optional type to avoid crashes.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

// Other setup code here

    let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: leftButtonString, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "navButtonClicked:")
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: rightButtonString, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "navButtonClicked:")

    // These tags are not a good solution because they aren't optionals!
    leftButton.tag = 0
    rightButton.tag = 1 // this isn't necessary, but I don't want it to crash...

// More setup here

}

func navButtonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Goes right by default
    let currentX = self.parentScrollView!.contentOffset.x
    var screenDelta = self.parentScrollView!.frame.width

    if sender.tag == 0 {
        screenDelta *= -1
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {() in
        self.parentScrollView!.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: currentX + screenDelta, y: 0)
    })
}
```

My current solution works, I'm just working towards writing cleaner code.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you set some title to your button, have you tried comparison based on button's title string in your `navButtonClicked:` method?

Comment: Or you can just subclass the UIBarButtonItem and add any kind of properties to it. I think that would be the cleanest way.

Comment: @RP The issue with that is I want to have unique names for those, such as "settings" or whatever, and nothing to do with going left or right.

Comment: @almas I considered doing that - you're right, it may be the cleanest solution, but I wasn't sure if sublcassing would actually be a clean solution. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:
Create two properties in your view controller that correspond to each UIBarButtonItem. This way you'll be able to tell which one was tapped.

Option 2:
Sublass UIBarButtonItem and add a property that you want.

Comment: I'll definitely look into option 1 - I feel like that's my favorite solution. Thanks for the response!